# The algorithm to get transaction history in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am looking for the details of how Hyperledger Fabric get transaction history for a specific asset, including what data structures and algorothms are used. In theory, the transactions of a specific asset should be stored in different blocks not in a sequence. That is, a linear search on all blocks in blockchain may be required to get all transactions of the specific asset. Is that right? Is there any document and code about this issue recommended to read? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**History is not fetched from the ledger.**

1.Unlike state data which can be stored in leveldb or couchdb History data is stored in a separate datastore and it is leveldb.

2.History data store should be enabled for each peer.

3.That can be done by enabling it in the core.yaml file in

> ledger->enableHistoryDatabase set to true

or else pass the env variable

> `CORE_LEDGER_HISTORY_ENABLEHISTORYDATABASE=true`

to the container for which you want to enable history database.

**How History for the same key is stored in history database.**

1.Now as it is a nosql database it cannot store a duplicate key.So some unique data is appended to the key and then the data is stored in the leveldb.

2.Querying the history database the gethistoryforkey API uses a query something like this

```
leveldb::Iterator* it = db->NewIterator(leveldb::ReadOptions());

for (it->Seek("theKey");
       it->Valid() && it->key().ToString() < "theKey~";
       it->Next()) {
    ...
  }
```

As you can see the key is split  from the unique data and then we get all the data related to it from the db.

Hope this helps.